# Is it possible to test alexa "Audio Player" interface without an echo device

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We are developing an Alexa skill to stream a playlist. And need to test it.

Have tried echosim.io , Reverb and Amazon Development Console simulator but none of them support audioplayer directive.
Can we test a skill in development on the Alexa android app?
Is there a way to test audioplayer directive without echo device

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test the skill that is in development on Alexa mobile app

Comment: Can you give OP some pointers on how to test their interface?